# How do I convert a DWORD to HEX

Tags: c, hex, dword

I'm currently using C Builder:

> ```
> DWORD finalAddress = 0xFFFFFFFF;
> TListItem *ListIt;
> ListIt->Caption = finalAddress;
> ```

This will output:
4294967295 (which is 0xFFFFFFFF in DEC)

I want it to show 0xFFFFFFFF.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have access to C++ standard library, try this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::ostringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << finalAddress;

AnsiString ansiHex = AnsiString (ss.str().c_str());
ListIt->Caption = ansiHex;
```

This last assignment may not work - I do not have access to Embarcadero's headers, so I have no idea what's the type of `ListIt->Caption`. There may be need to perform additional conversion.

Comment: Pretty much better! thank you, but still that will result a String and the Caption is AnsiString, how i make the conversion?

Comment: @GuilhermeGarcia I edited the answer - I am not sure if it is going to work, but according to [this forum post](http://forums.codeguru.com/printthread.php?t=375155) it should :)

Comment: THANKS!!
btw this works:
ListIt->Caption = AnsiString(ss.str().c_str());

Comment: there is no :: operator in C, and the << operator does not like strings as operands.

Comment: I don't see any traces of C++ in the question. But I agree that the C tag was added later.

Comment: @wildplasser C Builder mentioned at the top of the question is actually C++Builder by Embarcadero.

Comment: But it says C builder. It could *actually* be C-- builder, C@# buider or even D^% builder. Yes, that makes sense.